# Wifi does connect in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 17.10

I just installed ubuntu 17.10.  My wifi adapter had no signal and could not connect.

I was able to use: `sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2` to get a good signal, and all the wifi in the area are now visible.

When I try to connect to my router and use the key from the router which has not changed in 3 years, the adapter repeatedly asks for the key over and over again and never connects.

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10 and rtl8723be, the only solution that works for me: https://appuals.com/ubuntu-16-04-to-17-10-wifi-and-ethernet-problem/